# How multiple listening for 204 - No Content response from API via NgRx Store

Tags: javascript, angular, ngrx

If I'm dispatching multiple times same request which returns 204 - No Content (`null`), Observable via CreateSelector from NgRx Store is triggered only once even if I'm creating new State via spread operator which creating new reference of State where I thought that it is signal that something is changed and Observable will listening for it. My problem is that I'm not able then to know in Component that request is done and I can hide spinner which indicate loading of search results.

I'm using Angular 8.x and also NgRx 8.x.
I tried to create `deepClone` of State via Lodash (for sure), without any changes on my problem.
I didn't try to use some Immutable Library but I guess that it will be the same result.

Reducer.ts:

```
.
.
case ActionTypes.SomeActionSuccess: {
  return {
    ...state,
    someState: action.payload
  };
}
.
.
```

```
export const getState = createFeatureSelector<SomeState>('someState');
.
.
export const getSomeState = createSelector(getState, state =>
  state.someState ? SomeStateVm.parseList(state.someState) : state.someState);
.
.
```

Effects.ts:

```
@Effect()
  someActionSuccess$ = this.actions$
    .pipe(
      ofType(ActionTypes.SomeAction),
      switchMap((action: SomeAction) => this.service.loadSearch(action.payload).pipe(
        map(result => new SomeActionSuccess(result)),
        catchError(() => of(this.store.dispatch(new ShowkNotification('Request wasn\'t loaded!'))))
      ))
    );
```

some.component.ts:

```
.
.
this.store.pipe(select(getSomeState)).pipe(
  tap(someState => console.log(someState))
);
.
.
```

I expect that console.log will be triggered always when I create new Reference of State.

Comment: you're selecting only this chunk from the store:  `someState`. So if it is not changed (this particular chunk) , it will not be triggered when you select it in your component. I guess it is not changed.

Comment: yeah, make sense. But u know I want to listening just for this specific part of State/specific request, so, it will be not useful to check whole State because whatever else can be changed. Have u an idea how to handle something like that?